# phpFox Template change

Tags: phpfox

I have installed phpFox and I have HTML( only html,css,js ) template. I want to change to my own html template instead of default template! I could to do this task! Please help me to change default template to my own html template. phpFox 3.3.0

Answer (score 6):

Go to your admin area.

Then

1. Create a new theme here.

   http://yousite.com/index.php?do=/admincp/theme/add/
2. Now create a new style here and select your theme

   http://yousite.com/index.php?do=/admincp/theme/style/add/

   add a new style here
3. Now go to folder

   yoursite/theme/frontend/

   Copy cosmic folder and rename it with the name which you had given in admin while creating style.

   Also rename folder inside this folder cosmic to new folder name.
4. Now you can change the html

   yourfolder/template/template.html.php
5. You can also change the CSS

   frontend\yourfolder\style\yourfolder\css\custom.css
6. Activate your theme

   http://yousite.com/index.php?do=/admincp/theme/

   And make your theme default

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: I did it what you said but I found there {header},{body} etc. How can I fully change and fully install my own template?

Comment: A theme may not have all the html.php files for a complete theme. It effectively contains diffs. If you want to override any of the files, you need to create those files in that themes folder. for example, welcome.html.php to change the welcome area message

Comment: Could some one help where to find {header} block. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you tell us what exactly you want to modify or change. For instance if you want to change user profile head information, you should find the related template file from module "user". 
Anyway before doing it I suggest you to backup the original files.
If you want just to create a template with new styles, then do as KESHU VAT's way.